# Gtk Text View widget changing size of my window

Tags: gtk

I am attempting to learn how to use GTK. I am familiar with Java's JSwing, but having a difficult time controlling GTK widgets.

Below I create  a window and add a table container (which I assume is like a LayoutManager). I also add a Text View (which is similar to a JTextArea) in the first cell.

When I start typing in the text view and when my text passes the edge, my window grows. How can I make the window stay the same size and have scrolling ability in the Text View?

```
#include "window.h"

void window_create(ChatWindow* window)
{
    //Allocate the actual window. Our ChatWindow object has a pointer to a GTKWidget called window
    window->window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    //Set the size of the window
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window->window), 250, 180);

    //Close the program when they click the x button
    g_signal_connect(window->window,"delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    //Show the window
    gtk_widget_show(window->window);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window->window),"Chat Program");

    //Setup the Window
    window->chatHistory = gtk_text_view_new();      //Allocate the new TextView


    window->layout = gtk_table_new(4,4,TRUE);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(window->layout), window->chatHistory, 0, 1, 0, 1 );

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window->window), window->layout);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window->window);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `GtkTextView` inside a `GtkScrolledWindow` and it will gain scrolling capabilities. The scrolled window will also make it not grow in size.